# div backgroundImage withd input result

Tags: javascript, image, input

I'm using this tech : [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to get images from local clients, i don't want save it on my server. Can i (in javascript) set a div backgroundImage width this image ?
Now this is my code :

```
var input9I1 = document.createElement("input");
                            input9I1.id = "input9I1";
                            input9I1.type = "file";
                            input9I1.name = "files[]";
                            input9I1.accept = "image/*";
                            input9I1.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
                            td20I1.appendChild(input9I1);
```

So it was the creation of the input and it work fine.
Now the function :

```
function handleFileSelect(evt){
imgageATraiter = evt.target.files[0];

console.log(imgageATraiter.name);
console.log(imgageATraiter.type);
console.log(imgageATraiter.size);
console.log(imgageATraiter.lastModifiedDate);
console.log(imgageATraiter.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString());

document.getElementById('boite5I1').style.backgroundImage = imgageATraiter.name;}
```

So what i want is how can i modify the "boite5I1" 's background with my image ? Is it possible ? Thanks to read and have a good day :D

Comment: read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312930/how-to-preview-an-uploaded-image-as-the-background-image-of-a-div

Comment: Tryed : document.getElementById('boite5I1').style.backgroundImage = "url('http://127.0.01/"+imgageATraiter.name+"')";  and document.getElementById('boite5I1').style.backgroundImage = "url('"+imgageATraiter.name+"')"; Don't work too.

Answer (score 1):

You should try below code in handleFileSelect function.

```
if (imgageATraiter) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('boite5I1')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(50)
                .height(50);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(imgageATraiter );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [nicael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael) the answer is :

```
function handleFileSelect(evt){
imgageATraiter = evt.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#boite5I1').css('background', 'transparent url('+e.target.result +') left top no-repeat');
}
reader.readAsDataURL(evt.target.files[0]);}
```

Thanks so much and have a good day :D